# Bucle WHILE en C++ no termina ejecución - No consigo seleccionar opcion en c++

Tags: c++, date, datetime, conversión-de-tipos

Estoy construyendo un programa en que el usuario pueda seleccionar una opcion mediante teclado.

> La idea es hacer un while o do while, en el que para salir del bucle
>   tienes que indicar una de las letras (l, a, c), pero mi problema es
>   que cuando se introduce l, a, ó c, **el programa no sale del bucle.**

**El código:**

```
char menu;
cin>>menu;
while(menu != 'l' || menu != 'a' || menu != 'c'){
    cin>>menu;
}
```

¿Sabéis cuál puede ser el problema?

Comment: si mirar mucho mas, tu while mira la variable menu y tu lectura dentro del bucle lee la variable opcion?

Comment: tienes razon, pero aun asi sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: deberían ser && y no ||

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías cambiar los OR por AND

```
char menu;

cin>>menu;

while(menu != 'l' && menu != 'a' && menu != 'c'){
    cin>>menu;
}
```

> Del modo que lo tenías, siempre , o será distinto de L, o será
>   distinto de a, o será distinto de c.